# Why 'every' electrical devices in an airplane are prohibited during landing and departing?

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, aviation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are personal electronics a risk to commercial aviation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/are-personal-electronics-a-risk-to-commercial-aviation)

Not only the electrical devices using EM wave (ex: Cellphone, RC car, ...), but other electrical devices (ex: MP3, Nintendo DS, ...) are also prohibited in airplane, when it's landing or departing.

I heard that using any electrical devices can corrupt communication between the airplane and the airport, but I don't think that my little MP3 player will corrupt the communication. And that claim doesn't make sense, I think, because it is true that RC car controller can corrupt listening radio broadcast, but I have never seen that a camera or an MP3 player corrupts radio broadcast or communication between cellphones.

Do electrical devices **that doesn't directly use electromagnetic wave** corrupts communication between the airplane and the airport? If those do, how much those corrupts?

Comment: They might simply not take any risks. Furthermore, the main issue probably is that even or especially small electronic devices can turn into projectiles during a harsh landing and injure people.

Comment: Then they should have **banned** every electronic devices even when the airplane is **flying**. However, many electronic devices aren't banned, except those using EM wave.

Comment: @JiminP: It should be OK as long they are stored away during start and landing, which is what you get told. These are the more dangerous parts of a flight.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer But things like MP3 player can be used while it's fixed..

Comment: @JiminP: Try telling this to an insurance agent. To repeat my point: Not allowing these devices to be used during critical parts of the flight reduces the injury risk. That alone would be a good enough reason to not allow their usage. However, there is no reason to completely banning them.

Comment: I understood your point.. then, how much are they dangerous? Is there any cases that electrical devices made some serious problems? (I know it can be a risk even if there's no case, but I want to be kinda skeptical)

Comment: I'd be somewhat more worried about a flying hardcover book than an ipod shuffle...

Comment: I think there was already a duplicate Q but can't find it

Comment: Electronics all leak EM waves to some extent as the current through the wires changes. Older electronics was less power efficient and might have posed a risk during the sensitive landing/takeoff. Proving that something poses no risk at all is expensive!