# Is there any legitimate reason as to why airplane mode should be used?

Tags: aviation, mobile-phones

On many devices such as smartphones there is an option for "airplane mode". When enabled all wireless forms of communication are turned off. The idea is this is somehow safer to the airplane, but is it? For example is there any evidence to backup the claim that cell phone signals interfere with aircraft?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/why-every-electrical-devices-in-an-airplane-are-prohibited-during-landing-and which in itself is a duplicate of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/are-personal-electronics-a-risk-to-commercial-aviation

Comment: I'll tell you what, one things for sure no one will ever figure this out, becuase no one is stupid enough as to risk it.. what if the cellphone gives some rare signal that makes the plane go into a nose dive and locks up, think before you ask stupid questions. Basic common sense it has happened before.

Comment: @SSpoke, "figuring this out" would involve reproducible tests under safe, controlled conditions. Not randomly turning on phones in mid-flight on a packed commercial airliner. (Although considering some airlines _do_ allow such electronic device usage in flight, it's apparently considered "safe enough" by at least some of the people making those kinds of decisions.)

Comment: @SSpoke To what "basic common sense" are you referring? That someone has turned his cell phone on, causing the plane to go into a nose dive? As far as I know there have been exactly zero plane crashes (or other incidents, for that matter) determined to be even partly caused by cell phone signals. On the contrary, I'd bet that on most, if not all, commercial flights, there is at least one phone whose owner forgot (or "forgot") to turn off, and yet planes are not dropping. "One thing's for sure" that, due to pressure from customers and cell companies, someone will in fact figure this out.